# How to use activemerchant with Shopify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, payment-gateway, activemerchant, shopify-activemerchant

How can I use activemerchant with Shopify? What things do I need to start and how to activate it on Shopify. So, could anyone help in this, please? Just guidance needed.